# How do I find the screen brightness with cmd on Windows?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a code that I am writing that can change the screen brightness according to user input, but this is based around the current screen brightness. Is there a way to obtain the screen brightness as an integer from command prompt?

In the past I have tried to do this by using the Power Config utility in cmd, but it failed. I tried looking it up and didn't find anything for Windows. The nearest solution I found was for IOS and Android.

I got lost after trying the following:

```
C:\Users\[me]>powercfg /q | find "(Display brightness)"
    Power Setting GUID: aded5e82-b909-4619-9949-f5d71dac0bcb  (Display brightness)

C:\Users\[me]>
```

I expected a value for screen brightness like '45' or '45%' to be returned, but it gave me a display ID instead. What do I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close.  Here is how you do it.

The format of powercfg is:

```
POWERCFG -SETDCVALUEINDEX <SCHEME_GUID> <SUBGROUP_GUID> <SETTING_GUID> value
```

To find out your information:

For `<SCHEME_GUID>`:

```
powercfg /q | findstr Scheme
Power Scheme GUID: a3e508ca-5ab1-4c55-bee1-9edfb71ba0a4  (HP Optimized (recommended))
```

For `<SUBGROUP_GUID>` and  `<SETTING_GUID>`:

```
powercfg /q | findstr Display
  Subgroup GUID: 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40ca19  (Display)
    Power Setting GUID: aded5e82-b909-4619-9949-f5d31dac0bcb  (Display brightness)
```

Now with the GUID values and brightness in percentage - lets say **23%** - like this:

```
powercfg -SetDcValueIndex a3e508ca-5ab1-4c55-bee1-9edfb71ba0a4 7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40ca19 aded5e82-b909-4619-9949-f5d31dac0bcb 23
```

**Edit:** To view current britness level:

Check your current settings with the `GUID`: `aded5e82-b909-4619-9949-f5d71dac0bcb`

Just let the `powercfg /q > current_settings.txt`.  Will save the output to `current_settings.txt` file and there search for the `aded5e82-b909-4619-9949-f5d71dac0bcb`.

For example mine:

```
   Power Setting GUID: aded5e82-b909-4619-9949-f5d71dac0bcb  (Display brightness)
      Minimum Possible Setting: 0x00000000
      Maximum Possible Setting: 0x00000064
      Possible Settings increment: 0x00000001
      Possible Settings units: %
    Current AC Power Setting Index: 0x00000046
    Current DC Power Setting Index: 0x00000032
```

The value denotes the percentage (%).  The increment can be done by 1% (as you can see).

There is even [MSDN page about the brightness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/display-settings-display-brightness-level)

Comment: I really appreciate this response, but I know how to adjust brightness from CMD already. My problem is with obtaining the brightness value BEFORE it is changed.

Comment: After messing around with it to see what I can get, I still don't understand how it can get me the current screen brightness. Decoding the decimal values only gets me random characters.

Comment: @TheATLASCGZ now I don't understand you.  For example: `0x00000064` is a hexadecimal number which means the maximum is *64%*.  My AC PowerSettings is at *46%* and DC is at *32%*.  Note: the maximum is not always 100%

Comment: Quick question:
When I have the brightness manually set to anything but 100% the AC value (the only one that changes for me) is set to 0x00000000.
So what now?

Comment: @TheATLASCGZ it is internal laptop screen or it is an external one?

Comment: Internal @tukan

Comment: @TheATLASCGZ That is weird maybe your power management is somehow corrupted?  Did you check it via GUI - power management if you change the scheme there what happens?

Comment: No change even though I modified the AC value

Comment: let's discuss this on discord instead. @tukan My username is NotTheATLAS#3239

Comment: @TheATLASCGZ I don't do discord.  There is a chat on SO so you can start chat and post link here.

Comment: The command doesn't work on my machines. Tried on 2 different laptops. The values get updated when I check with `powercfg /q` but I don't see screen brightness getting updated. tried both setdcvalueindex, and setacvalueindex

Comment: @SahilSingh sorry to hear that.  I have tested it on my HP notebook back then on Windows 10 and it worked.  Maybe you have a driver issue or perhaps some settings (like powersavings) do interfere.

Answer (score 12):

Query screen brightness

```
powershell -Command "Get-Ciminstance -Namespace root/WMI -ClassName WmiMonitorBrightness | Select -ExpandProperty "CurrentBrightness""
```

Change screen brightness

```
powershell -Command "(Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/WMI -Class WmiMonitorBrightnessMethods).WmiSetBrightness(1,<YOUR_BRIGHTNESS_INTEGER>)"
```